# How to digitally sign Inno Setup generated uninstallation file?

Tags: windows, inno-setup, digital-signature, uninstallation

[Windows Logo Program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Hardware_Certification_Kit) requires that the `unins000.exe`, generated by Inno, is signed.
The only way I devised to do that is by unpacking the installer, signing and then repacking it again. Isn't there an easier way?

I have found an Inno Unpacker, but I'm not sure about how to repack it.

Comment: What is WSLK ? Some sort of Microsoft Windows credentials? Please expand WSLK.

Comment: @Cameron I think the name changed since 2010, I expanded the name and provided a link to the latest incarnation of WSLK

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In version 5.2.4 of InnoSetup, a new [Setup] section directive was added to help sign setup.exe and the uninstall:

> Added new [Setup] section directive:
>   SignTool, which makes it possible to
>   further automate digital signing of
>   Setup and Uninstall. See the help file
>   for more information.

Source: http://www.jrsoftware.org/files/is5-whatsnew.htm

Comment: Further documentation at http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_signtool

Comment: Since I couldn't use variables in the SignTool directive, I made it point to an external script which could point to the certificate files.